# Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(2n+1)(2n-1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

According to Wolfram Alpha,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(2n+1)(2n-1)}=\ln(4)-1$$
However, I am not sure how to evaluate this series.

**Attempt**
$$\frac{1}{n(2n+1)(2n-1)}=\frac{A}{n}+\frac{B}{2n+1}+\frac{C}{2n-1}$$
$$1=A(2n+1)(2n-1)+Bn(2n-1)+Cn(2n+1)$$

Then, I got
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(2n+1)(2n-1)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n-1}\\
$$
I tried to view this as a telescoping series, but it did not turn out good. Can I have a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\sum_{n\geq 1} \left( \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n}\right) - \sum_{n\geq 1} \left( \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2n+1}\right) = \ln 2 - (1-\ln 2)
$$